# How define reverse polymorphic in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

### Tables

**parents**:

```
id  | child_type | child_id
--- | ---------- |--------
1   | Student    | 5
7   | Student    | 8
9   | Employee   | 3
15  | Employee   | 8
29  | Employee   | 12
```

**students**:

```
id  | name
--- | ----------
1   | Jerry
..  | ...
5   | Alex
8   | Tom
```

**employees**:

```
id  | name
--- | ----------
3   | John
..  | ...
8   | Mike
12  | Susan
```

---

### Files

**models.py**:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, AbstractConcreteBase
from sqlalchemy.schema import Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    id = Column(Integer, pirmary_key=True)
    child_type = Column(String)
    child_id = Column(Integer)
    child = relationship('Child', uselist=False)


class Child(AbstractConcreteBase, Base):
    name = Column(String)


class Student(Child):
    __tablename__ = 'students'
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'Student',
        'concrete': True
    }
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Parent.child_id), primary_key=True)


class Employee(Child):
    __tablename__ = 'employees'
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'Employee',
        'concrete': True
    }
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Parent.child_id), primary_key=True)
```

**main.py**:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine('mysql~~', encoding='utf-8')
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

    parent_success_1 = session.query(Parent).get(1)  # <Parent(id=1, child_type='Student', child_id=5)>
    assert parent_success_1.child.name == 'Alex'     # success

    parent_success_2 = session.query(Parent).get(15) # <Parent(id=15, child_type='Employee', child_id=8)>
    assert parent_success_2.child.name == 'Mike'     # success

    parent_failure = session.query(Parent).get(7)    # <Parent(id=7, child_type='Student', child_id=8)>
    assert parent_failure.child.name == 'Tom'        # failed
    # sqlalchemy.orm.exc.MultipleResultsFound: Multiple rows were found for one()
```

---

Parent has child pointer via (child_type, child_id).
So i want to access child by polymorphic by set child_type, child_id.

But when i use rails's belongs_to polymorphic style columns, I can not load polymorphic instance from parent.

If set `uselist=True (default)` in parent model like:

```
child = relationship('Child')
```

`parent_failure.child` returns:

```
[<Student(id=8, name='Tom')>, <Employee(id=8, name='Mike')>]
```

How can i set `polymorphic_on` to parent's child_type column for using it?

Comment: This is discussed in the documentation as [generic associations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/examples.html#module-examples.generic_associations). I think the approach you are looking for is [`generic_fk`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/_modules/examples/generic_associations/generic_fk.html).

Comment: @univerio thank you!