# SQLAlchemy polymorphic Many-to-Many-Relation with Association Object

Tags: sqlalchemy, many-to-many, polymorphic-associations

I have items of different type, say `City`, `Country` and `Continent`. And I have `Label`s. I want to be able to add multiple Labels to either `City`, `Country` and `Continent` objects. And each Label could have multiple items, too.

I cannot use table inheritance for defining `City`, `Country` and `Continent` here, since the models and their respective database tables are already existing and populated. Migrating the database to a different structure is impossible in my situation due to the size of the database. So I tried to make it with an Association Object, but I cannot figure out, how to create the relation from, say, `Country` to the Association in a way, that it only retrieves the lablables which have `lablable_type = "country"`

So, what I have looks like this:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Lablable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'lablables'
    label_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('labels.id'), primary_key=True)
    lablable_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    lablable_type = db.Column(db.String(100))
    labels = db.relationship("Label")

class Label(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "labels"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    caption = db.Column(db.String(200))

class Country(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "countries"
    lablable_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('lablables.id'))
    lables = association_proxy('lablables', 'label',
                         creator=lambda x: Lablable(x=label))
```

How can I design my models to achieve what I want?

Comment: I think what you're after is called a [generic association / foreign key](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/_modules/examples/generic_associations/generic_fk.html), as mentioned by @univerio [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322828/how-define-reverse-polymorphic-in-sqlalchemy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681053/flask-sqlaclemy-how-to-do-one-to-many-polymorphic-inheritance).

Comment: @IljaEverilä You are right. That's what I was looking for. Just didn't know the nomenclature of this is sqlAlchemy. Make your comment an answer if you like.

Comment: I think it'd serve the site better if you were to write a self answer with a working example. You'd have my vote.

Comment: I can do so (but the example is already in the sqlalchemy-documentation you just linked.)